# Resolvent homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

> resolvent Homogeneous equation $=> (x\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dy+(x-y\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dx=0$

My Attempt:

$u=\frac{y}{x}\  =>  y ′=u ′x+u$

dy=udx+xdu

$(x\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dy+(x-y\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dx=0$

$(x\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dy+x(1-\frac{y}{x}\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dx=0$

$(x\sin(u)dy)+x(1-u\sin(u)dx)=0$

$x\sin(u)(udx+xdu)+x(1-u\sin(u))dx=0$

Honestly, I don't know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand to get $$ux\sin udx+x^2\sin udu+xdx-ux\sin u dx=0$$ $$\implies-\frac{dx}{x}=\sin u du$$